# How to fetch JSON content values dynamically using JSON slurper in groovy

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I am trying to filter out the JSON response values by passing on few parameters dynamically. Below is the code.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Request 1").getPropertyValue("Response")
jsonresponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)

log.info jsonresponse.context["parameter"]
```

`context["parameter"]` stores the values from an Excel sheet and doing only a `log.info` for `context["parameter"]`, it shows those values correctly. Below is the output of the code `log.info context["parameter"]`.

```
Thu Dec 14 07:18:53 CST 2017:INFO:firstName
Thu Dec 14 07:18:53 CST 2017:INFO:lastName
Thu Dec 14 07:18:54 CST 2017:INFO:frNum
Thu Dec 14 07:18:54 CST 2017:INFO:notes
```

But when I execute the code

```
log.info jsonresponse.context["parameter"]
```

Result:

```
Thu Dec 14 07:20:41 CST 2017:INFO:[]

Thu Dec 14 07:20:41 CST 2017:INFO:[]

Thu Dec 14 07:20:41 CST 2017:INFO:[]

Thu Dec 14 07:20:42 CST 2017:INFO:[]

Thu Dec 14 07:20:42 CST 2017:INFO:[]
```

`log.info jsonresponse` yields the below response out of which I need to get certain values (values stored in the `context["parameter"]`)

```
Thu Dec 14 07:21:45 CST 2017:INFO:[{errorMessage=null, middleName=null, lastName=Kosnick, frName=Kosnick Steven H , mplastName=null, competeRgnTxt=null, doNum=null, gddUnitStDate=null, fdNum=null, mpfirstName=null, legalEntityID=null, noNum=null, contractType=Financial Rep, frNum=046426, offcNum=NO 091, notes=Active, fullTmeSrvDt=null, firstName=Steven, networkOfficeNum=091}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this :

```
log.info jsonresponse.context["parameter"]
```

Try this :

```
log.info jsonresponse[context["parameter"]]
```

This should resolve your issue :)

Comment: Or `jsonresponse."$context.parameter"` should work as well